# Conditioning on the current value of a stochastic process

Tags: pr.probability

I want to condition a stochastic process $X$ on the current value of another process $Y$ in a continuous-time setting. So I am looking for a process $Z$ such that for every fixed $t$, 
$$Z_t = E\big(X_t \big| \sigma(Y_t)\big) \quad \text{a.s.}\tag{1}$$ 
**Uniqueness** holds when $Z$ is required to be cadlag. Alternatively, uniqueness follows when $Z$ is required to be optional and 
$$Z_{\tau} 1_{\{\tau<\infty\}}= E\big(X_{\tau}1_{\{\tau<\infty\}} \big| \sigma(Y_t)\big) \quad \text{a.s.}\tag{2}$$
holds for every stopping time $\tau$. 
**Existence** follows by a monotone class argument for $X$ if I can prove that the process 
$$X(t,\omega)=1_{[a,b)}(t) 1_F(\omega)$$ 
admits $Z$ as in $(1)$ or $(2)$. Here $[a,b)$ is some interval and $F$ a measurable set. 
But I am not able to show this. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: You need to be more precise to get a meaningful answer. What exactly is "stochastic process" here? I mean, what kind of joint measurability/continuity/... w.r.t. $\omega$ and $t$ do you assume and want to preserve in the conditional expectation you want to construct? I mean, without any such restrictions, you can just extend to $N_t$ arbitrarily and there is nothing to talk about.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to make it more precise.

Comment: Which sigma field is F measurable with respect to in your indicator function? Perhaps more importantly what filtrations for X and Y are in the background?

Comment: Let me ask a simple test question to understand what you are looking for. Assume that $Y_t=tX_t$ and $X_t$ is some non-degenerate random process that is as nice as you want. What nice properties of $Z$ do you expect to get at and near $t=0$? If I understand things right, the conditional expectation conditioning on $Y_t$ is here $Z_t=X_t$ for $t\ne 0$ and $Z_0=EX_0$. Note that I can put that degeneration to many places simultaneously screwing things up quite a bit.

Comment: It is a standard setting with `$(\Omega,\mathcal F,(\mathcal F_t)_{t \in \mathbb R_+},P)$` a filtered probability space and $X,Y$ adapted to `$(\mathcal F_t)_{t \in \mathbb R_+}$`. By measurability of $F$ I meant $F \in \mathcal F$. The monotone class argument I am referring to is in [Rogers and Williams. *Diffusion, Markov processes and Martingales Volume 2*, chapter VI, theorem 7.1], see http://bookfi.org/dl/757256/2e9982

Comment: fedja your example is great and your concerns are right. I might be in a better situation because in my case, $Y_t$ contains *gradually* more and more information, but I do not understand yet. 

In my case, $Y_t$ is the a-posteriori distribution of an unknown Bayesian parameter $\la$ with Bernoulli distribution, i.e. $Y_t=E(\la | \mathcal F_t)$. $X_t$ is a $[0,1]$-valued process representing the strategy of an agent in a sequential decision problem. If $Y_t$ is introduced as a state variable to that problem, then $Z_t$ would be a Markov strategy that is as good as $X_t$.

Comment: You can do this by combining optional/predictable projection in forwards and reverse time, as along as you assume some properties on Y. Namely, that it satisfies a "strong-Markov" property in both the forwards and reverse time directions. Your question does not mention any assumptions on Y though.

Comment: I can assume that $Y$ satisfies a strong Markov property in both directions. But could you expand on how to combine the optional/predictable projection in forward and reverse time, and why the strong Markov property is needed? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes I could! But its getting late here so I'll post a proper answer later this weekend. The idea is that, assuming the relevant versions of the strong Markov property, optional projection commutes with reverse-time optional projection to give a result which is both optional and reverse-time optional, implying that it is a function of $(Y_{t-},Y_t)$ and time. Or use optional projection combined with reverse-time predictable projection to get a function of $Y_t$ and time. Or, predictable projection with reverse-time optional projection to get a function of $Y_{t-}$ and time.

Comment: ...ok, bear with me here. I'll get back with an answer when I have time.

Comment: I am still interested in updates on this! Optional projection commuting with reverse-time predictable projection...how does the bilateral Markov property come in?